# No available FullCalendar view plugins

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have noticed that this error happened when I use:

```
 plugins: ["interaction", "timeGrid"],
```

and disapear when I use

```
plugins: ["dayGrid"],
```

can anyone explain why ?

html page

```
<link
  href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<link
  href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is error detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I have added the link, now I have this error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined:     at e.add (main.min.js:6)
    at e.addPluginInputs (main.min.js:6)
    at new e (main.min.js:6)
    at fillCalendar (index.js:364)
    at Object.success (index.js:299)
    at j (jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4)

Comment: yes I do, it looks lkke I have errors that I did not had when I used Fullcalendar main.js fils in a folder locally.

Comment: and there us another one: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined :                                        at main.min.js:6
    at main.min.js:6
    at main.min.js:6

Comment: Well I do not have this error when I remove "interaction", from the plugin ! Why ? is the Fullcalendar 4 buggy version ?

Comment: It's not buggy, it can work fine with this plugin. What order did you list the plugin files in the script?

Comment: There could be a version problem for interaction . Can u try different version of it

Comment: @Çağrı there's no problem with the 4.4. version. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYvBPPp . OP probably just listed them in the wrong order or something. And also you can't suggest to use a different version of the plugin than is being used for the rest of fullCalendar - that is a good way to introduce more bugs instead.

Comment: @Lydiahalls P.S. the error you quoted above, seems to be a jQuery error...but fullCalendar 4 does not use jQuery. So it seems a bit strange. Are you sure the error is really related?